# How do the French say "bacon"?

Tags: vocabulaire, alimentation

I believe there is a cognate, perhaps spelled the same way, but meaning something different.

I have asked a few native French speakers.  They seem to agree that they have a word "bacon" but they are not certain that it has the same meaning as in English.

Comment: Which meaning of the word are you looking to translate? *Bacon* can mean different cuts of pork meat in English (and that's not counting the figurative meanings).

Comment: Images for [bacon](http://www.hellopro.fr/images/produit-2/2/9/1/herta-bacon-petit-dejeuner-fume-100-g-2111192.jpg) and for [tranches de pointrine fumée](https://s1.croquonslavie.fr/cdn/farfuture/xqmEZXGny1JsfA38jLHqjkxGaeolWNmPA5RmZTXOqvw/mtime:1445469159/sites/default/files/styles/mega_edito/public/images/product/principal/7613034423146.png?itok=HtYtebXb)

Answer (score 4):

[*The English Breakfast Society*](http://englishbreakfastsociety.com/) a son mot à dire à propos du [bacon](http://englishbreakfastsociety.com/back-bacon.html). Une image vaut mieux qu'un long discours:

[image]

Le bacon français ressemble au *Canadian Bacon*.

L'*American Bacon* se nomme poitrine en français. Elle peut être salée ou fumée. Lorsqu'elle est taillée en morceaux plus petits, on obtient des *lardons*. Elle peut également être roulée: elle se nomme alors [*ventrèche*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventr%C3%A8che_(porc)) dans le sud de la France.

Je n'ai jamais trouvé de *British Back Bacon* chez les charcutiers que je fréquente à Toulouse.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two things that might be named bacon in France.

The first one is made of [round slices of pork meat](http://www.charcuteriedeslimouches.com/17-le-bacon).

The other one made of long and rectangular slices of smoked fat meat and is also called *[lard fumé](https://www.academiedugout.fr/ingredients/lard-fume_524)* or [poitrine fumée](https://etdoncvoila.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/bacon-en-france/) in French.

Comment: In Québec Bacon is the latter. Also, never heard "lard fume".

Comment: jiliagre's #1: http://www.charcuteriedeslimouches.com/17-le-bacon   / jiliagre's #2 (lard fumé): https://www.academiedugout.fr/ingredients/lard-fume_524

Comment: @Laure Merci ! Liens ajoutés à ma réponse.

Comment: Merci, tout le monde.

Si je comprends bien, le produit qu'on appele _bacon_ aux EUA s'appele _lard fumé_ en France (aussi, je crois qu'on l'appele, le _lard_ tout court).  Mais à Quebec on l'appele _bacon_ comme aux EUA.  En France le mot _bacon_ est autre chose.

Comment: On appelle aussi souvent bacon en France ce qui se nomme bacon au États-Unis.

Comment: I've never seen or heard "lard fumé" in France; in my experience, bacon is referred to as "lardons" (which technically means "diced bacon").

Comment: @zabouti petite correction, on dit "au Québec" quand on réfère à la province. La capitale de la province de Québec se nomme Québec, donc l'utilisation de "à Québec" référerait normalement à la ville et non la province. :)

Comment: @alexandre-p-levasseur Merci.  J'ai du ententre les deux expressions sans comprendre la difference jusqu'à maintenent.

Answer (score 1):

In Quebec my personal experience is to say "petit lard" for American bacon, but "bacon" is also used.

Comment: Bonjour ! Votre propos m'a surpris (_petit lard_)... mais le [lexique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8408976) vous donne raison. J'ai une expérience différente, pour moi le _lard_, peu importe avec quel adjectif, c'est simplement du gras, en tant qu'ingrédient uniquement. Le _Canadian Bacon_ c'est le genre de truc où je me suis déjà fait avoir en commandant ça en pensant que ça allait être du bacon (comme du _American bacon_) et quelle déception ! C'était simplement du porc en tranches hahah, au final du _jambon_... Merci !