# Pourquoi 'bacon' se prononce-t-il comme en anglais ?

Tags: anglais, prononciation

Pourquoi *bacon* se prononce-t-il comme en anglais ? Est-ce un simple cas comme celui de *biftek* où un mot français à l'origine s'est transformé à travers l'emprunt à l'anglais ? (C'est ce que dit [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bacon#%C3%89tymologie) si je le lis bien.)

Depuis quand on trouve cette prononciation ? Et y a-t-il des variations ou est-ce que le mot se prononce /bekɔn/ (plus ou moins) partout dans la Francophonie ?

Comment: La prononciation n'est pas comme en anglais : (TLFi)  PRONONC. : [bekɔn] ou [bekœn]; c'est une prononciation sur le modèle de "cake" [kek]. [ɔn] et [œn] ne sont pas des prononciations anglaises (seulement le n est entendu en anglais, schwa being sometimes added in a careful pronunciation).

Comment: @LPH La prononciatio est bien évidémment basée sur /bejkən/ en anglais, les seules différences étant la monophthongisation du /ej/ et l'évitement du schwa dans la syllable stressée en la remplaçant par l'approximation /ɔ/ ou /œ/.

Comment: Oui, elle est _fondée_ sur l'anglais, mais ne disons pas "comme", ce qui signifie vraiment "sans différence", bien que parfois assez relativement. Vous voulez dire "non-stressée", probablement ? La diphthongue en anglais anglais est toujours "ei", sauf peut-être dans un accent régional.

Comment: Sujet interessant :) Le seul article que j’ai vue a ce propos est ici; https://gretagarbure.com/quelle-difference-entre-le-bacon-francais-et-le-bacon-anglais/

Comment: @ilsuffit Je le prononce plus comme en anglais je pense; bé konne. Le bé me fait penser au e anglais, et le konne comme le ´on’ anglais. Comme quand tu dit ON/OFF. Sinon le dire en francais me semble bizarre, car sa fait be/kon. Desoler si je marque pas en terme linguistique, pas expert dans cela

Comment: Déjà entendu la prononciation /bakɔ̃/, c'est celle que j'utiliserais naturellement si je ne me faisais pas reprendre et chambrer.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Merci, la phonétique c'est un sujet bien difficile pour moi, idem pour l'API alors je comprends.

Answer (score 4):

> [...]L'emploi récent, avec une prononciation flottante, est un emprunt (1884, dans le Dictionnaire des anglicismes de H. Höfler)
> à l'anglais *bacon* (v. 1330) qui avait lui-même été repris au moyen français avec
> le sens général de « viande de porc », avant de se spécialiser pour
> désigner le lard maigre salé et fumé. Le mot se prononce en général à
> l'anglaise, sauf au Québec où il semble continuer l'usage du XVIIe
> siècle. (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. Alain
> Rey, 2011, Robert, « bacon ».)

Ça ressemble à un [réemprunt](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9emprunt), [comme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/toast) [*un/une toast*](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871310) (pour une rôtie) ou peut-être finalement à une restauration avec un [emprunt phonétique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5444). Mais encore, de quelle [prononciation](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bacon#Prononciation) de *bacon* s'agit-il ? Wiktionnaire dit \be.kɔn\ ou \be.kœn\ mais il y a trois exemples audio dont [be.kʌn] puis, au Québec, [be(ː).kən], [be(ː).kœn], et [be(ː).kʏn]. De ma perspective (Québec, sud-ouest), c'est [l'audio](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3AFr-Paris--bacon--2.ogg) de France pour \be.kœn\ qui se rapproche le plus de ce qui m'est familier même si je semble dire [be(ː).kʏn], peut-être une prononciation dans ma région du Québec ou mon groupe d'âge ou je ne saurais dire. J'imagine que c'est ce que veut dire « prononciation flottante » et je serais surpris d'apprendre que généralement l'emploi au Québec soit celui du 17e ou [\ba.kõn\](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bacon#Ancien_fran%C3%A7ais)  ; je ne connais personne qui ne prononce à la française, sauf pour un nom de famille.

De plus, dans le [GPFC](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) (début 20e .s, Québec), on trouve une note sous l'entrée *bacon* :

> La prononciation de *bacon*, sinon le mot lui-même, est chez nous
> emprunté à l'anglais; de bacon nous avons fait bé:kœ'n puis bé'ki'n,
> comme *wa:gi'n* de *wagon*.

Ça ressemble à une stratégie de prononciation ou je ne sais quoi, puisque dans le même *Glossaire* on a *wagon* avec une prononciation à la française et non ce \wa:gi'n\. Peut-être qu'en anglais je prononce ainsi plutôt que /ˈwæɡən/.

On peut observer que la prononciation n'est pas incompatible avec celle en langue anglaise, [/ˈbeɪ.kən/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bacon#Pronunciation),  mais qu'il ne s'agit pas exactement de cette prononciation-là non plus, selon le cas, vu que la prononciation est « flottante ». On peut imaginer que la prononciation vient de la fin du 19e s., clairement après le 17e. Je ne sais pas quand précisément. Il y peut-être des [nuances culturelles](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43832/25619) au niveau de la variété des produits, qui orientent la prononciation.

Comment: Pour "wagon", je penserais non à la voiture sur rails dont une collection tirée par une locomotive donne un train, pour laquelle coexistent au Québec les prononciations  \va.ɡõ\ et  \wɑ.ɡõ\ (la seconde en net recul depuis quelques décennies si j'ose me fier à mon expérience), mais à la grosse voiture de route style corbillard, prononcée encore aujourd'hui à l'anglaise (station wagon: variantes autours de /steɪ.ʃʏn.wɑ.ɡʏn/).

Comment: @Pasunclue Merci j'avais pas allumé pour le _station wagon_, je vais retoucher la réponse un autre tantôt.

Comment: Je me demande aussi maintenant si les petits véhicules de collecte de minerai dans les mines n'auraient pas été appelés /wɑ.ɡʏn/ à l'époque. La méthode de minage n'est plus très courante, aussi la disparition de cette prononciation dans les registres familier et professionnel ne saurait surprendre, mais il y a 70 à 80 ans au Québec, nombre de termes miniers étaient pris directement de l'anglais et leur prononciation simplement adaptée au système phonétique français.

Comment: Et hop! une nouvelle réminiscence du passé. Il me semble que mon grand-père et même mon père utilisaient /wɑ.ɡʏn/ (au féminin d'ailleurs) pour un traîneau attelé à une motoneige et destiné à sortir le bois de chauffage de la forêt. Quelqu'un d'autre se rappelle quelque chose approchant?

Answer (score 3):

Je pense qu'il y a une subtilité. Bacon peut en effet désigner 2 viandes/charcuteries différentes. Je vais parler pour la Belgique, mais je crois que ca serait aussi valide en France, je préfère ne pas me prononcer pour le Québec. Désolé d'avance aussi car je ne maîtrise pas l'alphabet phonétique...

1. Pour désigner certaines parties du porc (poitrine, ventre, dos) qu'on généralise sous le terme [lard](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lard). On s'en sert pour faire des lardons, des tranches plus ou moins fines (plus épaisses pour la choucroute, plus fines pour les burgers par exemple). Il est généralement considéré comme un article de **boucherie**. Celui-là est communément appelé "lard" en Belgique. J'avoue avoir découvert à l'instant que le lard pouvait venir du dos, je n'ai jamais remarqué de dénomination plus spécifique pour distinguer dos et poitrine en Belgique. Le terme "poitrine de porc"  (pour peu que l'on parle effectivement de la poitrine) est je pense plus commun en France, sans être totalement inconnu en Belgique. Ce "bacon" là, on le prononce "**à l'anglaise**" (avec plus ou moins de réussite quant à l'accent). Plus particulièrement quand les tranches sont fines d'ailleurs...

[image: Lard - Tranches épaisses]
[image: Lard - Tranches fines]
[image: Lard - Bloc]

2. Pour désigner le filet de porc fumé (généralement fumé en tout cas). Celui-ci est généralement utilisé en tranches assez fines et relativement rondes/ellipsoïdales. Il est plutôt considéré comme un article de **charcuterie**. Il est également beaucoup plus maigre que le lard. Dans ce cas là, on le prononcera généralement "à la française", comme "balcon", mais sans le "l".

[image]

Je tiens à préciser que je ne m'imagine pas commander à mon boucher 1 kg de "bayconn" sans devoir préciser ce que je veux exactement. A vrai dire, je ne pense pas que j'emploierais ce terme avec mon boucher, je demanderais simplement "1 kg de lard en tranches de x cm d'épaisseur" ou "1 kg de  lard en tranches coupées très finement". Peut-être même en précisant la destination (pour une choucroute, pour des hamburgers, ...)
Par contre, si je parle d'un burger au "bayconn" , ou d'oeufs au "bayconn", tout le monde s'attendra à ce que les tranches soient relativement fines...

Quelques sources :

- http://gretagarbure.com/2016/11/23/quelle-difference-entre-le-bacon-francais-et-le-bacon-anglais/bacon-francais-greta-garbure/
- [How do the French say "bacon"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/how-do-the-french-say-bacon)

Comment: Je suis moins culinaire qu'en Europe, pour moi le _lard_ c'est du _gras_, un truc utilisé pour rehausser le goût d'une viande maigre, qu'on voit piqué sur du rôti. Je ne connais pas les tranches rondes, pour moi c'est soit du jambon tranché épais ou un rôti tranché (mais ce serait tranché après la cuisson) ou de la saucisse présentée en forme de tranches rondes (mais évidemment ça n'a pas la texture de viande de ta dernière image). Par ailleurs je reconnais la troisième image comme étant du _pork belly_ mais je ne connais/n'utilise pas le nom en français pour ça (ce serait poitrine j'imagine).

Comment: Ton propos est intéressant, j'imagine que ça dépend de la relation que la personne a avec le boucher. Pour moi le bacon c'est un truc que j'achète sur les rayons, pas directement du comptoir du boucher. En fait je n'ai jamais acheté du bacon d'un comptoir ou en parlant à un boucher de ma vie. J'achète dans ce genre d'[emballage](https://globalnews.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/maple-leaf-bacon.jpg) uniquement.

Comment: Il m'est déjà arrivé de faire les 2. Et quand on l'achète pré-emballé, je ne me souvient pas de l'avoir vu appeler bacon, mais plus généralement lard ou encore "lard petit-déjeuner"